# A list of alternating interval between its components

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I create a list of the following numbers in a table automatically?

```
list={3 π/10, 7 π/10, 13 π/10, 17 π/10, 23 π/10, 27 π/10, 33π/10, 37π/10,....}
```

I wanted to use `(4n-1)π/10`, but it doesn't make sense. The interval between numbers is:

```
(4, 6, 4, 6, ....)*π/10
```

Also, we can see the period which has the behavior as:

From 0 to `π`

```
[0, π],,(4n-1)π/10
```

and

```
[π, 2π],, (4n+1)π/10
```

etc.

Comment: What is the `list`? It makes no sense as is, it is not a proper list, nor list of list, nor...

Comment: Why does the pattern change between 27 and 30?  The next element for the pattern would be 33

Comment: So Sorry, I made a mistake I just have corrected. I do apologize for my last mistake. You are right

Comment: "If you don't like to think"?  Is `FindSequenceFunction` only for the non-thinkers?  lol

Comment: O, my god, Mathematica is so powerful and wonderful.

Comment: @Kuba, I got what you were saying as soon as I used the function.  This machine learning could really put me out of a job someday :-)

Comment: @JasonB, and @Kuba, let see at :`list3 = {1.5 \[Pi], 2.5 \[Pi], 3.5 \[Pi], 4.5 \[Pi], 5.5 \[Pi], 6.5 \[Pi], 7.5 \[Pi]};`  I think the sequence is `(2n-1)\[Pi]/2` But Mathematica can't find it!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Ackaran - you are right about the sequence.  The documentation for 'FindSequenceFunction` says "The sequence elements $a_n$ can be either exact numbers or symbolic expressions" - so it will only work on that sequence if you replace 1.5 with 3/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet anoteher way:

```
Table[((Mod[n + 1, 2]*4 + 3)/10 + Floor[(n - 1)/2]) π, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another, simple way:

```
Riffle[#, # + 4 Pi/10] &@ Table[(3+i) Pi/10, {i, 0, 30, 10} ]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
π(Accumulate[Flatten[ConstantArray[{6, 4}, 10]]] - 3)/10
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick, don't know if it's the simplest, but I only recently discovered `Reap` and `Sow` so I use them all the time now

```
list = Reap[
        iter = 3*(Pi/10); 
        Do[Sow[iter]; 
           iter += If[OddQ[n], 4, 6]*(Pi/10);  
        , {n, 10}]][[2,1]]

(*
{(3 π)/10, (7 π)/10, (13 π)/10, (17 π)/10, (23 π)/10, (27 π)/10, (33 π)/10, (37 π)/10, (43 π)/10, (47 π)/10}
*)
```

Or, following Kuba's suggestion

```
func = FindSequenceFunction[{(3 π)/10, (7 π)/10, (13 π)/10, (17 π)/10, (23 π)/10, 27 π/10}];

(*
-(1/20) \[Pi] ((-1)^#1 + 5 (-1)^(2 #1) - 10 #1) &
*)

Table[func[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

gives the same

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Table}, SetAttributes[Table, SequenceHold]; 
 Table[Sequence[3 π/10 + i π, 7 π/10 + i π], {i, 0, 5}]]
 (* {(3 π)/10, (7 π)/10, (13 π)/10, (17 π)/10, 
     (23 π)/10, (27 π)/10, (33 π)/10, (37 π)/10,
     (43 π)/10, (47 π)/10, (53 π)/10, (57 π)/10} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[n_] := π/10 Range[3, 10 n + 3, 10]~List~Range[7, 10 n + 7, 10] // Transpose // Flatten
```